# Enabling camera video capture on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, raspberrypi, camera

Ubuntu 20.04 has an ARM64 version that should work out-of-the-box on the Raspberry Pi 4, and indeed it does.  However, I cannot figure out how to get video from the native camera which connects with a ribbon cable.  I'm using ROS2/OpenCV to access the camera like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(10)
print( cap.isOpened() )
```

and I always get `False`.  I'm inputting device number `10` to `VideoCapture()` since there is no `/dev/video0`, only `/dev/video10`, `/dev/video11` etc.  Does one need to somehow mount a camera before it works?

Below are the full errors I get from my code:

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Device '/dev/video10' is not a capture device.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (887) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video10): can't open camera by index
```

The key point seems to be: `Device '/dev/video10' is not a capture device`.  So how then do I get a capture device?

So I think the key problem is how to get the Raspberry Pi to create a `/dev/video0` file that points to the camera.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer that should get /dev/video0:

1. Edit the file `/boot/firmware/config.txt` adding two lines:

```
     start_x=1
     gpu_mem=128
```

2. Save the file and reboot
3. In a terminal, run   `sudo apt-get update`
4. In that same terminal, run `sudo apt-get upgrade`

This is a partial answer because things like Open CV capture or other methods to read the camera still do not work for me.  I get GStreamer warnings and errors afterwards.

Comment: I had tried that without success in using OpenCV too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at dmesg on your RPi, then you should see something like this:

```
$ dmesg
...
[    3.892570] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    3.924273] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    3.944425] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 4 channels
[    3.954828] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 4 channels
[    3.994725] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    3.994784] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.001545] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.027570] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.028170] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.029063] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.055371] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[    4.055899] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[    4.056430] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[    4.059344] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[    4.059378] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[    4.059398] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[    4.059414] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[    4.059427] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[    4.059529] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    4.059569] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    4.068348] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    4.068389] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    4.071323] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[    4.078793] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    4.078836] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
...
```

This tells me, that there are several video devices initialized - some for input/capture, some for output, some as DSP for encode/decode (H.264 on the RPi4, plus MPEG2/MPEG4/VC1 on earlier RPi).

I'ld suggest you try it with the device that is mentioned as "Device node capture[x]", in my case /dev/video14 or ...15 (the RPi4 has 2 camera interfaces as stated [» here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/libcamera/csi-2-usage.md)).

Comment: Ah, very interesting.  I'll try that when I get access to the device.

Comment: Ah, so I tried this:
`dmesg |grep video

[    9.674622] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    9.922092] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Pro Webcam C920 (046d:082d)
[    9.923080] uvcvideo 1-4.4.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 3 was not initialized!
[    9.923081] uvcvideo 1-4.4.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[    9.923083] uvcvideo 1-4.4.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized! 
...`

So it seems I somehow need to initialize my camera.  Any idea how?

Comment: This seems like a completely new problem with a USB attached webcam, not the RPi camera interface (CSI). Didn't you have a device /dev/video10 before? Is this another device/kernel?Now the kernel seems to have a problem initializing that external camera *and* there's no camera devices initialized for the RPi camera interface. As uvcvideo is an API within the kernel, a kernel update might help, but just a guess. You'ld need to provide some more information regarding those questions above.

Comment: I got a little more insight.  Redoing `dmesg |grep video` (after a reboot) I get lines like you show including: `[   10.911366] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00` and `[   11.003457] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14`.  But when I try to access `video14` with OpenCV it hangs until I ctrl-c.  And after doing this, everything is uninitialized like my above `dmesg`.

Comment: Hm.. If your video devices vanish, then there should also be some messages coming up in dmesg, because this seems to be a driver crash. Do you already have a csi camera attached? If not, this might just be the cause..

Comment: Ah, are right. I checked on my device (which I have not had access to in a long time) and found that the ribbon was inserted incorrectly and the camera sensor damaged.  I'll need a new camera before I can address this.  Thanks for your insights!